# Upload file with java web application but not using Java servlet

Tags: java, web-applications, web

I want to upload file server by using java language on server side but I don't want to use Java servlet for this.I have done with servlet. How is it be possible without servlet.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use an MVC framework like Spring and create a controller that can deal with multipart requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring MVC, and upload files. You can have a look at this link, it shall guide you to attain it without the use of servlets:
[Spring MVC - Uploading files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)